# Does "one ends" make sense?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> Connect one ends of these cables to this PC and the other ends to that
>   PC.

Is the "one ends" in the sentence above I created grammatically correct? After googled, I found this phrase is sometimes used by non-native speakers of English.

Comment: Why don't you make it so simple, like: Connect these cables from one end of this PC and the other from end to that PC.

Answer (score -1):

No, that's not syntactically / grammatically correct. '*one*' is always followed by a singular noun-phrase.

[Here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=_VERB_%20one%20ends%2C_VERB_%20one%20end&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C_VERB_%20one%20ends%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_VERB_%20one%20end%3B%2Cc0) is a comparison of "**_VERB_ one ends**", and "**_VERB_ one end**" on Google-Ngrams.

Following is an example sentence, from Cambridge dictionary, that contains [***one end*** (singular)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/end);

> She tied ***one end*** of the rope to a tree.

Comment: Your literal statement is false. *One **ends** a phone conversation by hanging up.*  In *that* construction, it's the plural that's always used, not the singular. You need to qualify your assertion to put it in context.

Comment: That's not a plural!

Comment: @JasonBassford, in "One ***ends*** a phone conversation by hanging up.", ***ends*** is a singular verb base form and not a noun.

Comment: @JasonBassford My statement--'one' is always followed by a singular noun-phrase.--doesn't negate the fact that 'one' can also be followed by other than noun.